Prove that $(A \times B)\setminus(A\times C) \subseteq A×(B \setminus C)$
I am just learning set theory. Based on this example I'm not sure how to find $x\in$ ? I would say that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, and that $y\in C$ is not true. This doesn't seem true though as we have the complement of $(A \times B)$ so $x\in A$ is not true. Could someone clear this up for me? Thank you!

Can you figure out what's happening for small sets? Say $A={a,b}, C={0,1}$ and $B={0,1,2}$?

If you know logical sentences( the math topic). Try analysing them , that may help.

Hint:  $(x,y)\notin(A\times C) \iff (x\notin A \color{crimson}\vee y\notin C)$

Based on the definitions involved, one concludes that:
\begin{align*}
(A\times B)\backslash(A\times C) & = \{(x,y) \mid ((x,y)\in A\times B)\wedge((x,y)\not\in(A\times C))\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid (x\in A)\wedge (y\in B)\wedge((x\not\in A)\vee(y\not\in C))\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid ((x\in A)\wedge(y\in B))\wedge(y\not\in C)\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid (x\in A)\wedge(y\in B\backslash C)\}\\\\
& = A\times(B\backslash C)
\end{align*}
In particular, the inclusion $\subseteq$ holds.
Hopefully this helps!

$(A \times B) \setminus (A \times C) $ is the set of $(x,y)$ where $(x,y) \in A \times B \land (x,y) \notin (A \times C$)
This means that $((x \in A \land x \notin A)\land y\in B) \lor (x\in A\land (y \in B \land  y \notin C))$
On the other hand, $(x,y) \in A \times ( B \setminus C) \iff x\in A \land y\in( B \setminus C)$
From here it's pretty easy to convince yourself that $(A \times B) \setminus  (A \times C) \subseteq A \times (B \setminus C) $
